# How to choose a random coordinate for the position of a turtle circle?

Tags: python, random, python-turtle

How do I get a python turtle circle to choose it's position randomly?
Here is my code for one circle:

```
asteroid.pencolor('white')
asteroid.fillcolor('grey')
asteroid.begin_fill()
asteroid.hideturtle()
asteroid.penup()
asteroid.speed(11)
asteroid.setposition(350,-200)
asteroid.pendown()
asteroid.circle(40)
asteroid.end_fill()
```

Comment: Use random numbers rather than the hardwired `350,-200`? Just `import random` and then use `random.randint`

Comment: check out the `random` module, specifically `random.randint(start, end)` where `start < x < end`

Comment: Start by reading some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random).

Answer (score 1):

Place this up top

```
from random import randint
```

And change your setposition to:

```
asteroid.setposition(randint({min-value},{max-values}), randint({min-value},{max-values}))
```

Where min and max-values are of course the minimum and maximum values you want.

https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/55c1eabde39efed2110002ae?locale=en

Comment: what do I do when it says:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'int'

Comment: do not add the curly brackets around your randint input, that creates a set. Just put the integers you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Python's `random` package. Specifically:

```
import random
random_point = (random.randint(min_x, max_x), random.randint(min_y, max_y))
```

This will give you random x and y coordinates, within the bounds defined by variables `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y`, and `max_y`.

Answer (score 0):

import the random module, and use the `randint` method. An example for a random number: `print(random.randint(1, 10))`
In this case, `point = (random.randint(low_x, high_x), random.randint(low_y, high_y))`

Answer (score 0):

****Probably Something Like The Following:****

```
import turtle
from random import *
asteroid = turtle.Pen()

asteroid.penup()
asteroid.goto(randint(-100,0),randint(0,100))
asteroid.pendown()

asteroid.pencolor('white')
asteroid.fillcolor('grey')
asteroid.begin_fill()
asteroid.hideturtle()
asteroid.penup()
asteroid.speed(11)
asteroid.setposition(350,-200)
asteroid.pendown()
asteroid.circle(40)
asteroid.end_fill()
```